# c# application that runs GPG commands

Tags: c#, service, gnupg

I am currently trying to create a `c# service application` that uses service to encrypt files and decrypt files using `gpg` commands automatically. Since there will be little to no user interaction, how do I implement inputting paths and file names to the service? Currently, I did a simple hard-coded `gpg` command in the service that runs the encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple option would be to configure input and output directories in your app.config and poll the input periodically using the  Timer class.

A slightly more complicated option would be to host a simple WCF service inside a win service that took input and output paths as parameters.